# unable to mount remote NFSv4 share from the client

Tags: centos, mount, nfsv4

Here's the premise:
I have **NFSv4** (only) server configured under Centos7 and running fine, here's the export (it's a sandboxed environment, so no security concerns):

```
server> cat /etc/exports
/export/dcs       *(sec=sys,rw,no_root_squash,sync,no_subtree_check)
server> cat /proc/fs/nfsd/versions
-2 -3 +4 +4.1 +4.2
server>
```

I know that NFSv4 server and its configured share work fine, because I'm able to mount it from the MacOS (Monterey) and from a remote docker container (under Centos7).

Problem:
However, on one particular machine (also Centos 7), after installing `nfs-utils`, I'm unable to mount the same share:

```
bash# rpm -qa | grep nfs-utils
nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.65.el7.i686
bash#
bash# mkdir -p /mnt/nfs
bash#
bash# mount.nfs4 10.1.2.3:/export/dsc /mnt/nfs
mount.nfs4: Protocol not supported
bash#
```

A) I know that tcp & udp nfs ports (2049) are reachable from the client - verified with `netcat`
B) when s-tracing the `mount.nfs4` I see this failure:

```
bash# strace mount.nfs4 10.1.2.3:/export/dsc /mnt/nfs
...
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP) = 3
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.1.2.3")}, 16) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(57709), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.4.5.6")}, [16]) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
mount("10.1.2.3:/export/dsc", "/mnt/nfs", "nfs4", 0, "vers=4.1,addr=10.1.2.3,client"...) = -1 EPROTONOSUPPORT (Protocol not supported)
...
```

The error that `mount()` call returns (`EPROTONOSUPPORT`) is pertain to some local / client's checks, because when I run `tcpdump` on the server, I observe that no single packet is sent by the client machine during `mount` operation.

I also tried mounting with: `LIBMOUNT_DEBUG=0xffff mount.nfs4 -vvv 10.1.2.3:/export/dsc /mnt/nfs` but it did not reveal any obvious failures:

```
bash# LIBMOUNT_DEBUG=0xffff mount.nfs4 -vvv 10.1.2.3:/export/dsc /mnt/nfs
5733: libmount:     INIT: library debug mask: 0xffff
5733: libmount:     INIT: library version: 2.23.0
5733: libmount:     INIT:     feature: selinux
5733: libmount:     INIT:     feature: debug
5733: libmount:     INIT:     feature: assert
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: ----> allocate 
5733: libmount:    UTILS: mtab: /etc/mtab
5733: libmount:    UTILS: /etc/mtab: irregular/non-writable
5733: libmount:    UTILS: utab: /run/mount/utab
5733: libmount:    UTILS: try write /run/mount/utab dir: /run/mount
5733: libmount:    UTILS:  access OK [/run/mount]
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: enabling flag 0020
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: enabling flag 2000000
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: initialized for [u]mount.<type> helper [rc=0]
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: enabling flag 0010
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: enabling flag 0010
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: enabling flag 0010
5733: libmount:    CACHE: [0x576b2158]: alloc
5733: libmount:    CACHE: [0x576b2158]: add entry [ 1] (path): /mnt/nfs: /mnt/nfs
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: use default optmode
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: OPTSMODE: ignore=0, append=0, prepend=1, replace=0, force=0, fstab=1, mtab=1
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: fstab not required -- skip
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: mount: preparing
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: OPTSMODE: ignore=0, append=0, prepend=1, replace=0, force=0, fstab=1, mtab=1
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: fstab not required -- skip
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: merging mount flags
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: final flags: VFS=00000000 user=00000000
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: mount: evaluating permissions
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: mount: fixing optstr
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: mount: fixing vfs optstr
5733: libmount:      CXT: applying 0x00000000 flags to '(null)'
5733: libmount:      CXT: new optstr 'rw'
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: mount: fixing user optstr
5733: libmount:      CXT: applying 0x00000000 flags to '(null)'
5733: libmount:      CXT: new optstr '(null)'
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: fixed options [rc=0]: vfs: 'rw' fs: '(null)' user: '(null)', optstr: 'rw'
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: preparing source path
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: preparing target path
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: final target '/mnt/nfs'
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: FS type: nfs4 [rc=0]
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Tue Apr 18 11:20:16 2023
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'vers=4.1,addr=10.1.2.3,clientaddr=10.4.5.6'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'vers=4.0,addr=10.1.2.3,clientaddr=10.4.5.6'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs4: Protocol not supported
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: syscall status set to: -1
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: prepare update
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: skip update: syscall failed [status=-1]
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: don't update: no update prepared
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: <---- reset [status=0] ---->
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: tabfiler disabled
5733: libmount:    CACHE: [0x576b2158]: free
5733: libmount:      CXT: [0x576b2008]: <---- free
bash#
```

What would be a reason for that error on the client (knowing it's not a result of protocol version negotiation)? And how further to troubleshoot this issue?

**UPD, extra debug info** (as requested by @aviro):

here's rpcdebugs collected during `mount.nfs4` operation:

```
Apr 24 14:52:52 nfsclient kernel: [13064.997882] NFS: nfs mount opts='vers=4.1,addr=10.1.2.3,clientaddr=10.4.5.6'
Apr 24 14:52:52 nfsclient kernel: [13064.997884] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'vers=4.1'
Apr 24 14:52:52 nfsclient kernel: [13064.997890] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'addr=10.1.2.3'
Apr 24 14:52:52 nfsclient kernel: [13064.997894] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'clientaddr=10.4.5.6'
Apr 24 14:52:52 nfsclient kernel: [13064.997897] NFS: MNTPATH: '/export/disco'
Apr 24 14:52:52 nfsclient kernel: [13065.000040] NFS: nfs mount opts='vers=4.0,addr=10.1.2.3,clientaddr=10.4.5.6'
Apr 24 14:52:52 nfsclient kernel: [13065.000042] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'vers=4.0'
Apr 24 14:52:52 nfsclient kernel: [13065.000047] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'addr=10.1.2.3'
Apr 24 14:52:52 nfsclient kernel: [13065.000050] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'clientaddr=10.4.5.6'
Apr 24 14:52:52 nfsclient kernel: [13065.000053] NFS: MNTPATH: '/export/disco'
```

And output with `strace -s1024`:

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/8mMZmgR8w9/

(posted there as the output is too big to fit here)

PS. please do not offer upgrading the `nfs-utils` RPM - the same one works fine from another spin-up (docker environment), plus it's beyond my control.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145569/discussion-on-question-by-dmitry-unable-to-mount-remote-nfsv4-share-from-the-cli); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Here's my last try: Can you check if you have the `nfsv4` kernel module loaded (`lsmod`)?  If not, can you try to load it (using `modprobe`)?